# Android socket program

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have created a simple android project using `socket` that sends `String` to `server` that is running on my Desktop. I have checked java code it is running perfectly. even my android `Activity` is running smoothly. connection that's invoked `onclick()` method. but when I am trying to run on my android device I got nothing on the server and nither receiving any error.
Thanks for help here is my Activity code

```
package com.example.controler;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    public void send_a(View v){
        try {

            Socket csoc = new Socket("x.x.x.x", 6666);
            DataOutputStream outToSerever = new DataOutputStream(csoc.getOutputStream());

            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csoc.getInputStream()));

            outToSerever.writeBytes("A");

            csoc.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `and nither receiving any error` We dont believe you: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: As @blackapps pointed out, you're not allowed to block the "main loop". Use AsyncTask, the Service class or Volley library https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple

Comment: AsyncTask  `doInBackground(Param...param)` method?

Comment: Yes, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: @momo and blackapps thanks now its working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the manifest permissions?

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: @ImtiyazKhan, additionally there is a great socket server/client called socket.io -> https://socket.io

Comment: Is the server in local network? Maybe localhost? Check If the android device can ping the server ip.

Comment: server is running on my Desktop Ip. i check it client(Java code) from laptop it is working

Comment: maybe your android device is not in LAN or not in the same LAN. Put your device in the same local network, with the same subnet e.g. Desktop 192.168.0.10, android device 192.168.0.XX

Comment: Both devices are connected to the same wifi

Answer (score -1):

Did you run on UI thread?try start a new thread to run it